# How Would I Create A Rails Click Counter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clone

I would like to make a rails click counter, similar to http://jenniferdewalt.com/click_counter/buttons/1
Thanks! I would like to know where to start, and how this works. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: you want to count clicks on particular link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by `Toby Kenobi`, it would be a relatively simple implementation.

You'd need two elements:

> 1) The "count" mechanism (just `before_action` in this case)
>
> 2) Storage (a `Model` we can tie to [`Redis`](http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html))

---

The way you'd implement it is like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "application#index"

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :click, only: :index

   def index
      @clicks = Click.sum
   end

   private

   def click
      Click.create
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use something like the following:

```
<%= button_to "Click Me", root_path, method: :get %>
```

This would have to be accompanied by a "storage" system:

```
#app/models/click.rb
class Click < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.sum
      $redis.get "count"
   end

   def self.create value=1
      $redis.incr "count", value
   end
end
```

Redis actually has a `counter` pattern, which you can read about here:

http://redis.io/commands/INCR#pattern-counter

Comment: I am a newbie, so can you make a step by step tutorial? I am having trouble understanding this. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly simple thing, and might be overkill using Rails to do it. The `jenniferdewalt.com` example just uses javascript and some Google API, and the code is obfuscated, so I can't see how it works. I don't know if the counter needs to update for the client when a different client clicks the button, etc.

To make the counter in Rails I would create a model with one integer attribute for the counter and have only one instance of the model in the database. Then the controller would fetch that model for the view. The view would send and AJAX request back to the controller when the button is clicked. The controller would increment the counter and save the counter object and return the new count to the view.

Comment: Thiis method would easily extend to having multiple click counters each with their own page. You'd just need to make more instances of the counter and put the counter id in the route.

Comment: Sorry if it is a little simple, I am very new to rails, and this is my first app that I am making with Rails.

Comment: @K.Shah no problem. If it's for the purpose of learning rails then this is a good project to do. I was just thinking that if it's for the purpose of having a click-counter then it would be easier to do without rails.

Comment: How else would I make it? With JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, with JavaScript, storing the total count as a text file on the server.